# Political countermeasures for "Web Environment Integrity"

Tags: european-union, internet, privacy

It looks like Google is trying to enable the "Web Environment Integrity" API, which will allow web servers to determine if the browser has been tampered with, e.g., using an ad-blocker or other software.

See the discussion here for more information on the proposed change: https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/157qif5/google_is_trying_to_destroy_distributed_web_a/

There have been several comments on the proposal, that show that the majority of the community is against this change, as seen in the issue in Github: https://github.com/RupertBenWiser/Web-Environment-Integrity/issues/

My question on this topic related to politics.SE is the following: Is there anything that normal web users within the EU can do to counter the implementation of this proposal, at least locally? E.g., if they were to petition to their representatives to the EU parliament, what exactly would they need to petition for?

In my opinion, the ability to use a custom web browser, that is not controlled by Google, is necessary for maintaining the free web that we are all used to, but is there anything that can be done to maintain the freedom of the web in light of the proposed changes by google?

Comment: Websites have been able to determine if you have ad blockers for a while now.

Comment: @JoeW: So in your opinion the "Web Environment Integrity" API is not going to diminish the user experience of web users in any significant way?

Comment: I don't know and that isn't a political question

Comment: @JoeW: Okay my question in the previous comment is not political, probably more suited for security.SE. However the steps to counter such a move within the EU regulations, as posed in the OP, *is* entirely political, no?

Comment: Again, you are making a claim about google doing something new when about something that is already possible and happening. Web sites have been detecting ad blockers for years and nothing about what you posted suggests that custom web browsers will blocked. I am not only unsure what exactly you are asking but how it relates to politics.

Comment: I kind of becomes a political question if you generalize it a bit. Some big company proposes to use some certain technology. You think this technology is dangerous and should ideally be forbidden or the industry be pressured not to use it. You want to efficiently campaign for that within the political system of say the US. How do you do it? Maybe ask like this.

Comment: @JoeW: It's not only about ad-blockers, the API will require a web browser that is *approved* by google. You won't be able to rely on open standard to consume any web service, as is the case now, because there is going to be a requirement for the browser to pass the equivalent of a "safety net". The political question is what can citizens of the EU do about this.

Comment: "...is there anything that can be done..." Boycott Google comes to mind.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution: That seems like a good solution for an individual, even though it comes at a big personal cost. But united there could be more leverege, I was thinking about a petition to be approved by the EU parliament that would allow the use of the services without the cost of this proposal.

Comment: @user000001 How is this fundamentally different from a software company requiring users to use a licensed copy of software? Or a hardware company that supplies software for their hardware (e.g. Apple) not allowing unlicensed use of things like app stores if the phone is e.g. jail broken. In a country with case law (e.g. the US) this clearly going to be seen as following established precedent.

Comment: @uberhaxed: I think that that the difference is that until now you could consume any web service with any browser, in a way similar to net neutrality. Now you are going to be required to install a specific "signed" browser in order to browse the web. Don't you see this as an attempt to make a free resource (the web) proprietary?

Comment: But I think I have commented enough on this thread, let's see how the rest of the community sees this issue

Comment: Again, all I see in your question is that the browser has not been tampered with, I don't see anything that suggests it has to be approved by google and google will be controlling the approval of all browsers.

Comment: There is no general human right to force commercial website owners to provide those sites in a manner which you deem appropriate. (Official government services would be another matter of course.) Unless your contention is that running adblock is a protected category such that it would be illegal to discriminate against you.

Comment: It might interest the reader to review copywrite protections on video codecs, if they want a similar scenario

Comment: Relevant https://www.theregister.com/2023/07/25/google_web_environment_integrity/

Comment: Firefox is fully open source, as well as Chromium, the engine running Chrome. -1 because this is a made up problem.

Comment: @JonathanReez: I think you are missing the point of this proposal. The browsers you mention will remain open source, but if you fork them, the fork will not be signed, so you won't be able to use it on most websites. Also the browser extensions will also need to be signed, so the user freedom will be severely limited.

Comment: @Cadence Europe has laws like GDPR, which actually do force them to provide those sites in certain manners.

Answer (score 4):

In general, the way for an individual citizen to influence a legislative body to act in a certain way (for example, to write a law to restrict certain activity) is to write to representatives of the legislature and to convince them that it is in their interest to act in your interests. You may send them some specifics of what you'd like them to do, maybe some draft legislation that you'd like for them to enact specifically such they they don't misinterpret your request. This is a political process called lobbying. Typically, individuals in the legislature get various opinions on an issue and take expert opinion, such as industry experts, more seriously than uninformed layman opinions.

When they go through this process of determining what their constituents want, because they are hearing different points of view they also look for a lot of concurring opinions to help make their choice. To that end, it may aid you in your lobbying efforts to find groups of people dedicated to your cause and to all write to the legislature. Perhaps you can even create an organization dedicated to your cause funded by donations to hire someone full time to talk to your representatives about your issue. This is called a political action committee. A generally less effective method, is to gather a bunch of people to say they individually agree with your statement. This is called a petition.

This process is well defined in countries like the US, so there are organizations designed for the purpose of creating these PACs and lobbying groups.
In the EU, you can use the following processes: [European citizens initiative](https://europa.eu/citizens-initiative/_en), which essentially requires you to make a petition and collect 1 million signatures (rather cumbersome, you'll want to hire some people to aid campaigning and collecting signatures). You can also get randomly selected to join the legislative initiatives and priorites process with the [European Citizens panel](https://citizens.ec.europa.eu/index_en) (rather unreliable, since the selection is random). And also the direct [Petition to the European Parliament](https://www.europarl.europa.eu/petitions/en/home), which does first require an EU policy already in place to affect you.

That said, I do find it unlikely that your specific issue will be addressed in the way you want. The primary reason for this is that 1. This is likely an issue that is related to already precedented issues. And 2. Expert opinion is more valuable than layman opinion. Google will strongly argue on the opposite side of this issue and may present this as a preemptive measure against AI or as a security measure against compromised machines. Possibly other industry groups will side with you on the issue but there is no obvious way for you to get involved. A better bet may be NGOs that lobby for consumer rights and data privacy, for example the [CCC](https://www.ccc.de/en/). They are a lot more likely to let you get involved and be grateful for any support. Since the members of parliament are infact full time politicians and not engineers, they will look at expert opinion in issues they are not well versed in (at least, I really hope that's how it works in the EU). This does occasionally transform into a phenomenon called regulatory capture, but honestly there's no good solution if every single expert is nefarious (which is unlikely).

Comment: The question asked specifically about EU political processes. You admit you don't know them. You havn't even taken the time to [look them up](https://european-union.europa.eu/live-work-study/participate-interact-vote_en). So what is the point of this answer?

Comment: @ccprog the point of the answer was to compel a person who knew the process but didn't want to write an answer to respond to me in a comment with a resource that answers the question so that I can write a complete answer without knowing all of the information.

Comment: A partial answer is better than no answer

Answer (score 4):

Switch to a non-Google browser, such as Firefox. The more people who are not using Chrome, the more afraid Google will be to ban all the non-Chrome users.

Switch your email, etc, to providers other than Google.

By the way, Edge is Chrome. Vivaldi is Chrome. Firefox is possibly the only independent browser remaining.

Answer (score 2):

I expect [Free Software Foundation](https://www.fsf.org/) to become active. They are very unlikely to agree with the idea that any browser built with the modified code will be not be able to fetch the content from the server. Looks like the topic will make a nice chapter in they [Defective By Design](https://www.fsf.org/campaigns/campaigns-summaries#dbd) project. Stay tuned on them, they are likely to provide the action items.

One of the obvious actions the typical user can very easily take is do not use Google Chrome for now. Use Firefox or something the like.

This project is also described at [The Registrar](https://www.theregister.com/2023/07/25/google_web_environment_integrity/).